Some invariant subsets of roots of unity
Let $n$ and $t$ be positive integers with $\gcd(t,n)=1$, let $C$ be the collection of all primitive $n$th roots of unity and let $S$ be a subset of $C$ such that, for every $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$(1)\qquad\sum_{z\in S}z^\ell=\sum_{z\in S}z^{\ell\cdot t}.$$
Is it true that $S=\{z^t\mid z\in S\}?$
If $S$ is a subset of $C$ which satisfies $S=\{z^t\mid z\in S\}$, then $(1)$ is clearly satisfied. I am asking if the converse is true.

Yes, but this has nothing to do with roots of unity -- if for two multisets $A, B\subset \mathbb{C}\backslash {0}$ we have $\sum_{z\in A} z^l = \sum_{z\in B} z^l$ for all $l\in \mathbb{N}$ then $A = B$.

Sorry, but why is that true? Am I missing something obvious?

For simplicity assume that $|A| = |B|$ (add zeroes to make it true). Then put $p_A(z) = \prod_{t\in A} (z-t)$ and the same for $p_B$ and show inductively that their coefficients coincide, starting from the highest one. Then their zeroes coincide, that is $A = B$ up to zeroes. If there were no zeroes to begin with, $A = B$.

Or, without induction, consider the rational functions $f(z)=\sum_{t\in A} z/(1-tz)$ and $g(z)=\sum_{t\in B} z/(1-tz)$, they have the same Taylor expansion at 0, thus they coincide as functions, and their poles with residues at them are the same, so $A=B$ as a multiset.
